# Passing Large, Complex Objects in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm coding a project for fun that requires custom objects within custom objects (like: All_Animals, All_Dogs, All_Labs, My_Lab type stuff). The thing is is that I need to pass an object from one activity to another but the object has ArrayLists of other custom objects as variables. I could obviously turn everything into strings and pass it through with putExtra(), but that would require a LOT of extra code and keeping things persistent and organized would get tricky.

Anyway, my question is what is the best way to pass a complex custom object with ArrayLists as variables from one Activity to another in java (specifically in android)?

Comment: Maybe use database? This gives you the benefit of not re-retrieving from REST calls. And you can be sure that you only get the data you need at certain time.

Comment: The answer is Parcelables... Even with strings (say you make it all JSON), you have a size limit on that data

Comment: Also, `All_Labs` should probably be `List<Lab>`, for example. You don't need a class only to hold "all items"

Answer (score 0):

Passing big data(including base64 images) into the Intent might be a problem in older phones(such as Samsung S4 Mini).
I would prefer database in these kind of scenarios. If you don't want to use database, you can serialize your objects using `Parcelable` and save it.
Another approach is, use Gson library to serialize objects and save it into `SharedPreferences`. Then in second activity receive it by only key.

```
//first activity
List<A lot of objects> list;
String jsonList = new Gson().toJson(list);
SharedPreferences preferences = context.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("UNIQUE_LIST_KEY",jsonList);
editor.commit();
Intent intent = new Intent(context,SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("LIST_KEY","UNIQUE_LIST_KEY");// pass only key to second activity/fragment

//second activity
SharedPreferences preferences = context.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String listJson = preferences.getString(getIntent().getStringExtra("LIST_KEY"),null);//get UNIQUE_LIST_KEY from intent and get string from preferences
if(listJson != null){
    List<A lot of objects> list = new Gson().fromJson(listJson, new TypeToken<List<A lot of objects>>(){}.getType());//
}
```